# ttest results in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, statistics

I am computing those three matrices

```
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6]';
B = [50987548463 45764568 606978 7318 1674 4]';
C = [50 45 60 78 1 4]';
```

Why on earth does 
`ttest(A,B)` **returns 0** (no rejection of null hypothesis, which means the means are the same with 95% confidence level) while
`ttest(A,C)` **returns 1** (rejection of null hypothesis, which means the means should be different with 95% confidence level)

I would expect rejection of null hypothesis for both ttest, but even more for ttest(A,B)!!

Comment: `ttest(A,B)` returns `0` for me.

Comment: You should ask this question on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: hi! thanks for your answers, I have edited the question, indeed it was the other way around (sorry). I will try on Cross validated..but I wonder if it's not just a misunderstanding on how Matlab computes it..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mean and standard deviation of (A-B) set are high, but t-statistics is -1.0011, which is sufficient to reject H0. Mean and std of (A-C) are smaller, but t-statistics is -2.7612, which is not sufficient to reject H0 with only 5 degrees of freedom. You can check it using

```
[h1,p1,ci1,stats1] = ttest(A,B) 
[h2,p2,ci2,stats2] = ttest(A,C)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer...but I can't find in Matlab the equations for the ttest, and again, to be it doesn't make sense..! could you explain me more?

Comment: you are right...thanks. now I need to understand better the meaning of the ttest

Comment: Wikipedia provides some introductory information (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-test), and some examples you can find here (http://www.socialresearchmethods.net/kb/stat_t.php)